# How to set background?

Tags: html, css, background

I need to set a background image.. for the area which my site will not be using, throughout.

http://oi61.tinypic.com/903z4l.jpg

I need to add a background image in the GRAY part of the site.

My HTML code:

```
<html>
<body>
<?php include 'banner.php'; ?>
</body>
</html>
```

The banner and navigation code, I have set them to center and 800px in banner.php, as u see in the pic:

```
#nav 
{
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
width:800px;
}
```

Comment: Make a div which is where you want the background to be than as css use `background: url('something.png');`

Comment: background: url(path/to/image.jpg);

Comment: Do you have a div where you want your background to be exactly? If yes use `background: url(background.png);` on that div if your background image name is background.png and in the same folder as your html page. If it's in another folder use `background: url(folder/background.png);` where folder is of course the name of your folder.

Comment: Thanks @DejaVu.. Worked quiet well with.. DIV :) thnks!

Answer (score 1):

Add a `background` to the `body` of the HTML. This can be done with CSS.

**CSS:**

```
body {
    background-image:url("background.jpg");
}
```

**Note:** This background will repeat over and over, in order make it **non-repeatable** you could use:

```
body {
    background:url("background.jpg") no-repeat;
}
```

**Update:**

Your HTML code needs to have a `div` with the `id` of `nav`, so it overlaps the background:

```
<html>
<body>
    <div id="nav"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

All the content you add into the div nav will now overlap the background.

Comment: It is setting the background entirely..I don't want it within the 800px.

Comment: add white color background of your php content.

Comment: It's setting the background entirely, but content overlaps the background, so you should add a div of 800px onto it.

Answer (score 0):

```
body{
   background:url('image.png');
}
.centerDiv{
   width:800px;
   margin:0 auto;
   background:#fff;
   height:100%;
}
```

That should work for you.